Convert Quantization to Onnx
I am new and want to try converting models to Onnx format and I have the following issue. I have a model that has been quantized to 4-bit, and then I converted this model to Onnx. My quantized model has a weight size of 7GB, but when I run the conversion to Onnx, my resulting model.onnx_data has a size of 34GB. Is there anything wrong here?
Below is my code:
from optimum.onnxruntime import ORTModelForCausalLM
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("SorawitChok/SeaLLM-7B-v2.5-AWQ")
ort_model = ORTModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
"SorawitChok/SeaLLM-7B-v2.5-AWQ",
\# "/content/SeaLLM-7B-v2.5_4b",
use_io_binding=True,
export=True,
use_cache=True,
from_transformers=True,
\# provider="CUDAExecutionProvider",  # Change this to "CPUExecutionProvider" using CPU for inference
provider="CPUExecutionProvider",  # Change this to "CPUExecutionProvider" using CPU for inference
)
print('=====Save Model====')
ort_model.save_pretrained("./SeaLLM-7B-v2.5-AWQ_onnx")
tokenizer.save_pretrained("./SeaLLM-7B-v2.5-AWQ_onnx")

Thanks for any help
I want to obtain the model that has been quantized and converted to 4-bit quantization.
